# iOS dynamically filling search results

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios4, uiscrollview

I am building a small Search app on iPad. I want to show the search results. Do I use `UIScrollView` or `UITableView`?

The number of search results are unknown & as the user scrolls vertically I'll want to dynamically keep fetching the results & fill whatever container I will be using. Something like what Google Reader (on web) has.

For this purpose which is better suited? `UIScrollView` or `UITableView`? Also please guide me as to how dynamically populate the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an awesome question. I have a different approach for a solution to this problem. It is not the exact answer; But I would assume that the logic might be helpful -

Algorithm:

1. Decide on a certain number of records being pulled into the UITableView. (lets say 8 ).
2. You can use a UIScrollView with a small size (rather than setting it with smaller stepping size & frame).
3. Using the clipsToBounds property (set it to NO), you can actually track the amount of scroll, and check if it goes out of bounds
4. After you go beyond the bounds, initialize a new UIScrollView with a fresh-list of tables, and get another 8 data entries, and this can be continued.

Reduce the size, set the property and it would work.

But the problem with this is that ; if you try to touch outside the scrolling area => it will not scroll up/down.

Please refer to [this](http://blog.proculo.de/index.php?url=archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html)  tutorial, which can offer some intel  on this idea.

And for setting the Scroll amount for Page control => Refer to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674458/defining-scroll-amount-with-uiscrollview-and-pagecontrol)  on Stack Overflow.